# Get youtube video comment details using PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, youtube, youtube-api, gdata-api

I'm trying to get youtube video comments for a given video using PHP. I'm using Zend framework. Following is my code snippet

```php
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_Youtube();
$feeds = $yt->getVideoCommentFeed($id);  // $id is youtube id
while ($feeds) {
     foreach ($feeds as $idx => $feed) {
          echo $feed->getTitle()."\n"; // work and display the beginning of comment
          $author = $feed->getAuthor(); 
          // how to get author name and/or id?
          $date = $feed->getPublished();
          // how to get the date out if it?

     }
     $feeds = $yt->getVideoFeed($feeds->getNextLink());
}
```

How can I get author's name/id, published time and other information for each comment? I couldn't find that information from Zend documentation.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
$commentFeed = $yt->getVideoCommentFeed('abc123813abc');

foreach ($commentFeed as $commentEntry) {
    echo $commentEntry->title->text . "\n";
    echo $commentEntry->content->text . "\n";
    echo $commentEntry->author[0]->name->text. "\n";
    echo $commentEntry->author[0]->uri->text. "\n"; 
    echo $commentEntry->published->text. "\n";
}
```

For the Vlogbrothers Feed:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/og8cxXICoVU/comments
```

A Sample comment entry

```
<entry>
    <id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/og8cxXICoVU/comments/z13tuzmrbk2cszxbx04cjdcoyva4jjliu0c</id>
    <published>2014-03-09T20:16:01.000Z</published>
    <updated>2014-03-09T20:16:01.000Z</updated>
    <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#comment"/>
    <title type="text">i also highly ...</title>
    <content type="text">i also highly recommend Chop socky chooks- ninja chickens with a piece of 
wasabi as their arch nemesis.</content>
    <link rel="related" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/og8cxXICoVU"/>
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=og8cxXICoVU"/>
    <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/og8cxXICoVU/comments/z13tuzmrbk2cszxbx04cjdcoyva4jjliu0c"/>
    <author>
      <name>Jade Collins</name>
      <uri>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/NGsitBKTSKzO-Fioyjy4dw</uri>
    </author>
    <yt:channelId>UCNGsitBKTSKzO-Fioyjy4dw</yt:channelId>
    <yt:googlePlusUserId>118173943933565439685</yt:googlePlusUserId>
    <yt:replyCount>0</yt:replyCount>
    <yt:videoid>og8cxXICoVU</yt:videoid>
  </entry>
```

Comment: Thanks, archie. It's very clear when I look at the comment entry now. I was trying to print_r each comment and it looks so murky. Thanks

Comment: To avoid paging too many times, I'm trying to increase the number of feeds per page. I tried $commentFeed.setItemsPerPage() but it does not have any effect. Just wonder if you know how to achieve that? Thanks.